# How to insert custom view into XML's LinearLayout

Tags: android, view, android-layout, android-xml, android-custom-view

So I have a `CustomView` which is extended from `View`. And I have a linear layout from XML.
The XML named `example`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/jembalang.comfest.game"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <jembalang.compfest.game.GameThread
    android:id="@+id/game_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </jembalang.compfest.game.GameThread>
  <Button 
    android:text="Button" 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code using the xml

```
setContentView(R.layout.cobagabung);
gameView = (GameThread) Jembalang.this.findViewById(R.id.game_view);
gameView.setFocusable(true);
gameView.setFocusableInTouchMode(
gameView.start();
```

I added the GameThread constructor if that's helping

```
public class GameThread extends View implements Runnable,OnKeyListener{
    public GameThread(Context context,AttributeSet attr){
        super(context, attr);
        ...
    }
    public GameThread(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ...
    }
```

I think there is something wrong with my way doing it, because the `findViewById` returns `null`
How should I do to make my `CustomView` (`GameThread` at this example) to be able inserted into xml?

Comment: are you actually using complete package?

Comment: use merge tag instead of Linear layout at top level

Comment: @Jinda um, yeah, I looking at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/layout/custom_view_1.html and it giving complete package.

Comment: @vnshetty No, it still didn't work :(

Comment: @dieend provide your custom view

Comment: @vnshetty the constructor? I have added it.

Comment: @dieend sorry i dint get where you are missing. you better debug your code with breakpoints . your custom view should be initialized when your setContentView is get executed...

Comment: @dieend Show us your logcat so that we could better trace what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Your line should read:

```
gameView = (GameThread) Jembalang.this.findViewById(R.id.game_view);
```

you are passing the id of a layout rather than that of the view you have created.

The rest of your code looks fine

Comment: Ah, sorry. I mistyped it. It's actually like your written. But no, the gameView is still a null.:(

Comment: Why do you have to fully qualify your this pointer for the Jembalang.this.findViewById call? are you making the call on the same object that you added the view to?

Comment: The gameView implements Runnable, and I need to start it, that's why I need call it again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `Jembalang` is but I think you should remove that.

```java
gameView = (GameThread) findViewById(R.id.game_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You say your layout file is called "*example.xml*", but you call *setContentView(R.layout.**cobagabung**)*. Thus, your view is initialized from "*cobagabung.xml*".

Make sure you use the same identifier for layout file name and setContentView call, like

```
setContentView(R.layout.example);
```