# VideoView / Layout for playing video on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I have a problem regarding Android App.
I have created an application that download video from server.
After that it play it on videoview.
But the problem is it can't play video on full screen, infact videoview is on set to fill parent.

[image]

Please help me regarding that it is very vital for me.

[image: this is my layout image]

My layout file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your VideoView in xml file just add the following attributes

```
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Use this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574654/playback-video-full-screen) might help you.

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" add this line in manifeat file and also remove android:gravity="center" also try to replace LinearLayout with RelativeLayout

Comment: yes i tried the above code its work good on my emulator.  
but when i install it on my tablet its not working fine...
even it is set any corner of my tablet not full screen
and if i rotate the tablet video is gone from screen only voice came.

Answer (score 3):

VideoView *wouldn't* try to fill the whole screen of your mobile as it needs to maintain the **aspect ratio** of the videos. It is important because if you break the aspect ratio, the video would fill stretched and many users wouldn't like it. But if you still want to go full screen , subclass VideoView like :

```
public class MyVideoView extends VideoView {

        public MyVideoView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
             setMeasuredDimension(480,800);
        }

    }
```

Comment: hi i create a inner class in my activity.
but as i run the program it gives an error on following code

[**bold**]video = (MyVideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);[**bold**]
so i can't run the program

Comment: you need to add this custom videoview "MyVideoView" replacing your original videoview tag  in layout xml . Just replace VideoView keyword with packagename.MyVideoView in your layout xml .For example look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186729/how-to-insert-custom-view-into-xmls-linearlayout